# how can I update google play services in eclipse

Tags: android

My question is that I have an android application which developed in Eclipse. I need to update Google play services but i don't know how to do that.
May you help me please how to update ?

Comment: that has nothing to do with eclipse. open SDK manager and tick Extras-> Google Play Services then press install packages.

Comment: actually i mean that i want to import google play services version 9.2 in my project. but when i look to updated play services it gives many think before it was under extras\google\libraries\google_play_services_lib like that. but now different. how it should be with new one ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all download updated google play services and import into project.

Comment: you mean download from sdk or from github somewhere ? if from sdk i updated but as i mentioned up the way is changed thats why dont know to add updated could you tell me please the exacly way ? thanks